# Why can't I click on my page button after closing wire-elements modal?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using wire-elements/modal (version 1.0.7) to display modals on click on table rows. I have to precise that the table is a livewire component.

But when I close the modal (just by clicking outside this one), I can't click on another rows on my table to display another modal. I have to refresh the page to click on another row.

It seems that th emodal component are still running...

But when I inspect with livewire Devtools :

when I open my modal :

```
activeComponent:"fa6d179c2d78dfd5686620efe2fbe09f"
components:Object
fa6d179c2d78dfd5686620efe2fbe09f:Object
attributes:Object
modalAttributes:Object
name:"contact-modal"
```

and after closing the modal :

```
activeComponent:null
components:Array[0]
```

Some errors shows in the console :

```
cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) {isFromCancelledTransition: true}isFromCancelledTransition: true[[Prototype]]: Objectconstructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()__proto__: (...)get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ app.js:1126
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
transition @ app.js:1076
out @ app.js:1017
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
window.Element._x_toggleAndCascadeWithTransitions @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
we @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
Yt @ cdn.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
r @ cdn.min.js:5
ln @ cdn.min.js:1
cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) {isFromCancelledTransition: true}
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ app.js:1126
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
transition @ app.js:1076
out @ app.js:1017
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
window.Element._x_toggleAndCascadeWithTransitions @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
we @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
Yt @ cdn.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
r @ cdn.min.js:5
ln @ cdn.min.js:1
cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u is not a function
    at cdn.min.js:5:9014
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
requestAnimationFrame (async)
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u is not a function
    at cdn.min.js:5:9014
```

Some codes to understand :

My modal blade view :

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>          
            <div>
                <p>{{$contact->firstname}} <span>{{$contact->lastname}}</span></p>
                <a href="{{route('clients.show', ['id' => $contact->client->id])}}">{{$contact->client->society_name}}</a>
                @if($contact->type)
                <p>{{$contact->type->name}}</p>
                @endif
                @if($contact->role)
                <p>{{$contact->role}}</p>
                @endif
                <p>{{$contact->phone}}</p>
                <p>{{$contact->email}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if($contact->phone)
            <a href="tel:{{ $contact->client->phone }}">Call</a>
            @endif
            @if($contact->email)
            <a href="mailto:{{ $contact->client->email}}">Email</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My livewire modal component :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Contact;
use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

class ContactModal extends ModalComponent
{

    public $contact;

    public function mount(int $contact)
    {
        $this->contact = Contact::find($contact);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.contact-modal');
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here :
[Laracast:livewire-modal freezing page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-modal-freezing-page)

Alpinjs is called twice on my app (with an unpkg link and the @livewire('livewire-ui-modal') directive).

So I remove the unpkg link and it works like a charm!